# How to add text to a pop up window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window

I'm creating a resume builder where a person can enter information into input fields and my javascript code will take the field values and write it to a popup window, which will be their resume. I'm clearly doing something critically wrong here. I can get the pop up window to open, but no text that I'm appending from javascript is in the popup window.

I'm going to show snippets of the code so I'm not posting full-on documents, but everything follows the same suit.

The code for my input html:

```html
<body>
    <!-- Full name -->
    <p><strong>Enter your full name:</strong></p>
    <input type="text" name="fullName" cols='75'><br>

    <!-- Address -->
    <p><strong>Enter your address:</strong></p>
    <input type="text" name="address">
     .
     .
     .
</body>
```

Html for my popup window:

```html
<body>
    <div id="name"></div>

    <div id="address/phone"></div>

    <hr>

    <div class="theLeft" id="objectives_pop"></div>

    <div class="theRight" id="objectivesText"></div>
    .
    .
    .
</body>
```

Javascript:

```js
function myWindow() {
    window.open("popupWindow.html", "_blank", "height=500", "width=500", "left=100", "top=100", "resizable=yes", "scrollbars=yes",
    "toolbar=yes", "menubar=no", "location=no", "directories=no", "status=yes");

    // Name
    var name = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;

    // Address and phone number
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var phoneNum = document.getElementById('phoneNum').value;
    document.getElementById('address/phone').innerHTML = address + '/' + phoneNum;
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to append text from input fields in my main html file (project.html) to the popup window in popupWindow.html. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code snippet you are calling `document.getElementById` on the main page, not the popup. You will first need to get the popup window as a variable, then modify it as needed.

To get you started, try doing something like the following:

```
let myPopup = window.open("popupWindow.html", "_blank", "height=500", "width=500", "left=100", "top=100", "resizable=yes", "scrollbars=yes",
    "toolbar=yes", "menubar=no", "location=no", "directories=no", "status=yes");

myPopup.onload = function() {
    var name = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    myPopup.document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name
}
```

This will open up a new popup window, wait for it to load, then change the name innerHTML of that popup, rather than the parent page.

Comment: I understand. However, after making the appropriate changes, it still is not writing to the popup. Is there anything else apparent that I am missing or messing up? I have my src tag in the head of the html document; I've tried moving it around to see if that would help but to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to modify anything in the popup? Try just running `myPopup.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>"` and see if anything gets displayed.

Comment: No nothing gets displayed. I noticed when opening inspect element in chrome I get an Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property  'innerHTML' of null. I'm not exactly sure what this means. This is for the line: myPopup.document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name

Comment: @Austinwc0402 Ah, it seems we'll need to wait for the page to be loaded. From my testing, this seems to work. Try my edited code.

Comment: This is my "Create Resume" button that activates the pop up window:               
<!-- Form button -->
<button id="button" onclick="myWindow()">Create Resume</button>                       What am I supposed to put in "onclick" if "myPopup.onload = function()" does not have a function name?

Comment: myPopup.onload defines a callback function. This code will go inside your myWindow function. The nameless function gets called once the popup is opened and loaded.

Comment: I have it like this: function myWindow() {
    popup.onload = function() {
        // Name
        var name = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
        popup.document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = name;                         But it's still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203559/discussion-between-tristan-wiley-and-austinwc0402).

Answer (score 1):

You are using document.getElementById() but on your html the inputs actually have no id, they have names, your html should be:

```
<p><strong>Enter your full name:</strong></p>
<input type="text" id="fullName" cols='75'><br>

<!-- Address -->
<p><strong>Enter your address:</strong></p>
<input type="text" id="address">
```

Comment: Ah! How embarrassing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like `<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none;">Insert text</div>` in your popup dialog!